# I am using ng-hide in angular but it's not working

Tags: angularjs, typescript

```
<nav class="menu-nav">
        <ul>
          <li class="menu-li" ng-model="myVar"><a>Search<i class="fa fa-chevron-down pull-right"></i></a>
          <div class="sub-menu" ng-hide="myVar">
            <ul>
              <li><a>Search-sub</a></li>
              <li><a>Search-sub</a></li>
              <li><a>Search-sub</a></li>
              <li><a>Search-sub</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-li"><a>Home<i class="fa fa-chevron-down pull-right"></i></a></li>
          <li class="menu-li"><a>Dashboard<i class="fa fa-chevron-down pull-right"></i></a></li>
          <li class="menu-li"><a>Register<i class="fa fa-chevron-down pull-right"></i></a></li>
          <li class="menu-li"><a>Login<i class="fa fa-chevron-down pull-right"></i></a></li>
           </ul>
      </nav>
```

Comment: Please post the code, and current error/output and expected output.

Comment: Can you put your code in a HTML snippet? Be sure to include the angular.js. There are many versions to choose from, try to match the version you are using. It may also need the associated CSS file if you are able to link that as well.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 2+ ng-hide won't work you can use *ngIf directive for hide and show element.

Example

**TS -**

```
    isLoading = true // change value as per your requirement
```

**HTML -**

```
<div *ngIf="isLoading">Loading... </div>
```

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

If we presume that you are using Angular2+ and not AngularJS: 
**ng-hide** is Angularjs directive, you can't use it in Angular2+. You can use ***ngIf** if you want your DOM elements to be actually rendered or not, and **[hidden]** which is equivalent of ng-show in angularjs, when you want your DOM element to be rendered but not displayed.

In your case, you can have a property in your **.ts file**:

```
 public loading: boolean = false;  // update this property when you have to...
```

And in your **.html template:**

```
<div class="sub-menu" *ngIf="loading">
  <ul>
    <li><a>Search-sub</a></li>
    <li><a>Search-sub</a></li>
    <li><a>Search-sub</a></li>
    <li><a>Search-sub</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```